# Is there a way to fix the DNS Routing bug in 84.06.06?

Tags: router, dns, routing, fritzbox

My research with forums and google searches hasn't turned up anything relevant.
I have lodged a service request with AVM, but not holding my breath.

**Overview:**
The Fritzbox adds static host routes to the wrong interface for the specified DNS servers.
The routes go out the DSL, but the DNS server is on the LAN.
The Fritzbox re-adds the routes when I delete them, then the networking breaks again.
Further this blocks the DNS server(s) from the internet as the packets are routed the wrong way.

**Details:**
Configuration has DNS servers specified by entries overwrite_dns1 and overwrite_dns2.
These entries worked fine in 84.05.04, but the bug was introduced when moving to 84.06.06.
There is no NAT involved here. All IP addresses are world routed (non-engineering).

**Proof shown below:**
in the output of "netstat -rn", with the IP addresses made anonymous.
The DNS servers are on the local lan, a Class-C is X.Y.Z.0
The Fritzbox is routing the DNS entries to the dsl.
This cuts off the DNS servers from the internet.
The internet connection is dsl, A.B.C.D

Removing the bad routes only works for a number of hours, then the bad routes come back.
The bad routes are removed with "route del X.Y.Z.10" and "route del X.Y.Z.11".

```
# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
A.B.C.D         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 dsl
X.Y.Z.10        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 dsl    <- Bad Entry
X.Y.Z.11        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 dsl    <- Bad Entry
192.168.179.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 guest
X.Y.Z.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 lan
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 lan
```

Perhaps there is config entry that stops the bad routing entry being created?
I don't want to revert firmware version as the current version fixes several security flaws, apparently.
Some kind of cron entry to keep deleting the routes would not entirely mitigate the problem.

Please help.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. What is a Fritzbox? What is it's relation to the DNS servers? What ip addresses do the Fritzbox and the DNS servers use?

Comment: As per the tag, the - FRITZ!Box Home Internet Routers manufactured by AVM in Germany.<br>The router has an IP address on each of the interfaces dsl (A.B.C.D), lan (X.Y.Z.40), and guest (192.168.179.1)

Comment: `As per the tag` - Nobody knows what FRITZ!Box Home Internet Routers are except people who use them, so the tag is meaningless to most of us here. What are the ip addresses of the Fritzbox? Presumably it has an external, public ip address and an internal, private ip address?

Comment: Are ip addresses X.Y.Z.0, X.Y.Z.10 and X.Y.Z.11 in the same subnet?

Comment: Yes, as per "a Class-C is X.Y.Z.0"

Comment: As there are some questions on this site tagged with Fritzbox, I was hoping there might be some people here who have found a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14715/discussion-between-nslntmnx-and-joeqwerty).

Comment: Understood but the majority of us probably don't know what they are. So the DNS servers and the LAN interface of the Fritzbox are all, say 192.168.1.1, .10 and .11? To be clear, they are all in the same subnet and use the same subnet mask?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should clarify the question. When I delete to bad routes, the routing is 100% perfect. But the Fritzbox keeps putting the bad routes back. Yes the DNS routers are all on the same subnet (class c) and have the same netmask etc. You are making an amazing effort that I am truely thankful for, but this question is related to Fritzbox.  Perhaps I should delete the question?

Comment: Sorry. I moved into the chat after my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the DNS entries from the DHCP server, or greatly increase the DHCP lease times, until the issue is addressed by the vendor.  The DHCP clients will refresh their configuration at 1/2 the period of their leases.